# How do I create a new project in an existing git-hub repository?

Tags: git

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't figure it out. I'm happy to use the website or the command line.

**EDIT: Say there is some repository/user named foo on GitHub, and there is a project named bar.**

**So, you could go to github.com/foo/bar**

**I would also like to create github.com/foo/bar2**

Sorry for my ignorance... I'm making the switch from SVN.

Comment: What do you mean by "project"? This is not a term from the git world. Do you just mean to clone the repository, add some stuff ("project") and then push the changes back to github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, first a note on terminology: if the URL is http://github.com/foo/bar, then

- `foo` is the user
- `bar` is the repository

Simply log in to github, go to your [Dashboard](https://github.com/) (the link at the top right), and look at the bottom of the page. There's a link "[Create a Repository](http://github.com/repositories/new)" there.

(I understand the reason for the question now. It took me a minute to find it, too...)